# Is a variety a CW-complex?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

How to establish that any differentiable manifold and any complex algebraic variety is a CW-complex ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: For manifolds this is part of Morse theory.

Comment: [For algebraic varieties](http://mathoverflow.net/a/26929/5506).